# SESSION in laravel for page protection

Tags: php, laravel, session

I want to make a Login Registration system in laravel 8. In which User when login only can access a particular page else redirect to login page. I did this like that. what's wrong in it.

//Login Code

```
 function login(Request $req){
        $results = DB::table('crud_users')
        ->where('email', '=', $req -> post('email'))
        ->where('password', '=', $req -> post('password'))
        ->get();
        foreach ($results as $value) {
            $value ->email;
            $value ->password;
            $name = $value ->name;
            $user_type = $value ->user_type;
            echo $id = $value ->id;
            session()->put('id', $id);
            session()->put('name', $name);
        }
        $req -> validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $email = $req -> input('email');
        $password = $req -> input('password');
        if ($user_type == 'admin') {
            if (($email == $value ->email) && ($password == $value->password)) {
            return redirect('admin');
            }
        } else if($user_type == 'user') {
            if (($email == $value ->email) && ($password == $value->password)) {
            return redirect('user');
        } else{
            return redirect('login');
        }
        
        
        
        // session()->flash('success','You are registered! Please login!');
        // return redirect('login');

    }
}
```

//Session Code

```
if (session()->has('id')) {
Route::get('logout','App\Http\Controllers\User@logout');
Route::view('user','user');
Route::view('admin','admin');
Route::view('edit/{id}','edit/{id}');
}else{
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... i think you should look into laravel middleware and learn more about laravel

Comment: Sorry for late response sir. Yes sir I was beginner at that time. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the default authentication in laravel8 **using laravel application Jetstream starter kit** and use the `auth()` middleware to go to a particular page.
you can see this [[blog](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-8-authentication-tutorial)][1](https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-8-authentication-tutorial)

or see the laravel's documentation from [[here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication)][2](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication)

for your code you're i think you're call `session` by this way `session()` it's wrong you should call the session class or use this way like this `$request->session()->has('id')`

or

```
Session::has('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use like following code

```
Session::put('id',$id);

Session::put('name',$name);
```

And in your conditional value you have to use like

```
if(Session::get('id')!=''){
    Route::get('logout','App\Http\Controllers\User@logout');
    ...
}
else{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `auth()` middleware for login authentication.
for more info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication